# Insert Custom row into cart after adding a product

Tags: php, magento

I have grouped product , and when i click on add to cart i want to set show some custom value into the cart.
I am doing this with observer with following code

```
 public function addPostData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
                $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
                if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {
                if($action->getRequest()->getParam('fname')) {
                    if($action->getRequest()->getParam('lname')) {
                $lastName = $action->getRequest()->getParam('lname');
                        }
                        $item = $observer->getProduct();
                         $additionalOptions = array();
                         $additionalOptions[] = array(
                            'label' => 'First Name',
                            'value' => $action->getRequest()->getParam('fname'),
                         );
                        $additionalOptions[] = array(
                            'label' => 'Last Name',
                            'value' => $lastName,
                        );

                        }
```

and i am getting all needed value from grouped product page to cart but
how can i show an array value into the cart with every group item or is there any way to insert a custom row into the cart using observer event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood it, but wouldn't a for each($observer) work to create an array that you can show?